# PHP version is 7.0 but getting "php7.0-fpm: unrecognized service"

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04

I recently upgraded an Ubuntu 14.04 server to PHP 7.0. Everything seemed to go smoothly. However, even after a server reboot, if I do `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart` I get the error `php7.0-fpm: unrecognized service`

When I run `php -v` I can see it is running PHP 7.0.10.

If I check `service --status-all` I can see `php5-fpm` in this list instead of 7.

What's going on here?

Comment: Php-fpm is a separate package/application from php. Php interprets files containing php code, php-fpm speaks the fastcgi protocol with webservers. So look for a php7-fpm package in whatever source you found php7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS @JonahB mentioned in comment, you have to install the `php7.0-fpm` package as well:

```
apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

You may also want to remove the previous one, even if it's not mandatory:

```
apt-get remove php5-fpm
```

Comment: I removed php5-fpm, but it is still showing up in the service list. How do I remove it completely?

Comment: @eComEvo, try `systemctl daemon-reload`